# How to resize navigation bar button

Tags: ios4

There are lots of posts on navigation bar but i need to resize it.

Means in my application it get bigger with each view. But i want to keep it smaller in size with all views.

How can i resize that and if possible put an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize a navbar button -- or to customize it in any way -- you need to create a custom `UIBarButtonItem` to add to the navbar.

The following code snippet will create a customized `UIBarButtonItem` that contains a custom button with normal and highlighted images on it and is sized to be the same size as the image:

```
UIButton *customButton = nil;
UIImage  *buttonImage = nil;
UIImage  *pressedButtonImage = nil;

buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_image"];
pressedButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_pressed_image"];
customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[customButton setImage : buttonImage forState : UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setImage : pressedButtonImage forState : UIControlStateHighlighted];
[customButton addTarget : self action : @selector(buttonTapped) forControlEvents : UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
customButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height}];
container.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[container addSubview:customButton];

UIBarButtonItem *customToolbarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:container];

// add the custom button to the toolbar
self.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addButtonItem;
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. i put your code in my rootviewcontroller class's viewDidLoad() method. UIBarButtonItem *customToolbarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:container]; it says unused   variable customToolbarButton and does nothing.

Comment: Raj -- you have to add the customBoolbarButton to your toolbar.

Comment: i am making this button for navigation bar left hand side one. clicking which takes you one view left.

Comment: //back button
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [backButton release];