# how to resize the info button in attributes inspector

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

How can I resize the info button [image](this round button with a letter i inside)?

I have tried to drag it in the storyboard to resize it. But Xcode does not allow to do that.

I also tried to change its size in attribute inspector or size inspector. Neither works.

So how to resize it? Do I have to resize it programmatically? If so, can anyone provide me an example?

This question may be naive. But this is my first time to use info button in iOS. Surprisingly, I did not find any similar question online.

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Why not use a custom UIButton with image matching info button?

Comment: AFIK, info button can't be resized. The guidelines don't allow you to reduce the size & it is not cool to have larger info button than standard size.

Comment: @Thought-Beast do you know how to implement the flip anime when i click the info button?

Comment: @DragonZ Just search, and you'll find it. That's separate from your first question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize navigation bar button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904621/how-to-resize-navigation-bar-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CGAffineTransform to resize the button and to implement the flip animation you asked in the comment use UIView transitionWithView method. The code is like : 
To reduce the size of button, I just scaled to 50% with scale transform

```
_infoButton.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_infoButton.transform, 0.5, 0.5);

- (IBAction)infoButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
                       } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: The question is about how to change that via `size inspector` which is in `interface builder`

Comment: Unable to set the frame size with size inspector in IB.